# $scope issue with push angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    $http({
    url: "php/Insert.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
        'amount': $scope.amount,
        'salesId': $scope.currentSalesId,
        'uId': userId
    },
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        $scope.tasks.push({
            "salesId": $scope.currentSalesId,
            "amount": $scope.amount,
            "uId": userId,
            "taskId": data
        });

        })
```

my push doesn't work as **$scope.amount & $scope.currentSalesId** is undefined. I bet it is scope issue, the data did goes into backend and work after I refresh, but my front end is broken. I couldn't put the push outside the $http because I want to use its call back which is the **data**.

Answer (score 0):

as a fast solution you can do that

```
var myAmount=$scope.amount;
$http({
url: "php/Insert.php",
method: "POST",
data: {
    'amount': $scope.amount,
    'salesId': $scope.currentSalesId,
    'uId': userId
},
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.tasks.push({
        "salesId": $scope.currentSalesId,
        "amount": myAmount,
        "uId": userId,
        "taskId": data
    });

    })
```

I need the whole .js page to give you a better answer 
as I'm wondering why $scope.amount is undefiend, but $scope.currentSalesId is defiend

Comment: so I need the whole .js page, so I can help you :)

Comment: when I put outside of $http then it's good, but I need to use the callback (data) in my push. No need whole page of js, this is just function of my ng-click

Comment: there is a trick some times I do when things go wrong in angularjs 
I define 
var scope //before the controller function
function Controllerxyz($scope){
scope=$scope;
//then I can use scope.anything
//any time any problem happens 
}
I wish that solve your problem 
best regards